# SendToOfficialFile submitterEmail not working

Tags: 2010, records-center

Using the SendToOfficialFile method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee546921.aspx) I move documents to the records center. The problem is that the "modified by" field is not updating with correct value.

When I enter a valid value in parameter submitterEmail I get this error in log:

```
<nativehr>0x81070e25</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>The user or group 'SERVERNAME\user@email.com' is unknown.
```

When I try with a username I get this error i log:

```
Begin Query the AD to get the user email and display name.
End Query the AD to get the user email and display name.
 The user does not exist or is not unique.<nativehr>0x81020054</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>
User Administrator did not already exist in web; adding user now
The user does not exist or is not unique.<nativehr>0x81020054</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>
```

Also tried different other values but without any success.
Anyone got this working? Or know why this errors occurs?

Comment: You can use `SPWeb.EnsureUser(string logonname);` before you query it. This checks the login, and if it isn't found it will add them to the AD Information List.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.ensureuser

Answer (score 0):

can you check to see if the user is valid also the domain name, can you query the database to see if the use exists?

> I saw this problem a few times but when I went to user profile, I can
>   see the user is there and all the information is right. But if you go
>   to WSS_Content db and run

```
select * from userinfo where tp_title like ‘user%’
```

> I found the tp_login data is different from the user who has problem. The problem
>   with this, is that the tp_Login column in the UserInfo table for every
>   site collection in which Margie has permissions, is cached with her
>   previous NT Login Name. There is also no way to update this
>   information with a SPUser object from the SharePoint object model, and
>   SharePoint does not synchronize this from Active Directory once the
>   users is added to a web in the Site Collection.
>
> The only time that SharePoint will automatically update the tp_Login
>   column, is if the users is completely removed from the site
>   collection. The tp_Deleted column is then set for the user in that
>   site collection. On the next occurrence of the user being added to a
>   web, we gather the current information from the domain. You can
>   however, re-sync SharePoint with the current information without
>   removing them completely from the site collection by using SPUserUtil 
>   For a single user you can use

```
stsadm.exe -o migrateuser -oldlogin MYDOMAIN\prhranki -newlogin MYDOMAIN\LUHRANKI -ignoresidhistory
```

> If you need to do a batch of users, I personally think WSSUserUtil and
>   SPSUserUtil is the way to go.

http://littletalk.wordpress.com/2009/12/14/the-user-does-not-exist-or-is-not-unique/